# How to vectorize this loop in Python loop requiring uniquesness and non-uniqueness check?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array (`edges`) of size `3xn` and it contains exactly two rows where the first two elements of the row match and third element might or might not match. I am computing some stuff based on this criteria. My for loop based code goes along these lines

```
mat = np.zeros((edges.shape[0],2),dtype=np.int64)
counter = 0;
for i in range(edges.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i+1,edges.shape[0]):
        if  edges[i,0]==edges[j,0] and edges[i,1]==edges[j,1] and edges[i,2] != edges[j,2]:
            mat[2*counter,0] = i % nof
            mat[2*counter,1] = i // nof

            mat[2*counter+1,0] = j % nof
            mat[2*counter+1,1] = j // nof
            counter +=1
            break
```

where `nof` is a specific number.  How can I speed-up this code using numpy? I cant use `np.unique` as this code requires uniqueness as well non-uniqueness check.

For example, given:

```
edges = np.array([
    [1,2,13],
    [4,5,15],
    [5,6,18],
    [1,2,12],
    [4,5,15],
    [5,6,18],
    ])
```

where the first two elements of each row can be found in another row (that is they are duplicated exactly twice) and `nof=1`, the above code gives the following result

```
[[0 0]
 [0 3]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

Comment: can you paste a small example of the input data, and expected output to make the question more clear?

Comment: As an aside, no need for semi-colons in Python

Comment: @jeremycg I update the code with an example. Hope it is clear enough

Answer (score 2):

I haven't absorbed how you are setting `mat`, but I suspect lexsorting on the first 2 columns might help:

```
In [512]: edges = np.array([
     ...:     [1,2,13],
     ...:     [4,5,15],
     ...:     [5,6,18],
     ...:     [1,2,12],
     ...:     [4,5,15],
     ...:     [5,6,18],
     ...:     ])
     ...:     
In [513]: np.lexsort((edges[:,1],edges[:,0]))
Out[513]: array([0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5], dtype=int32)
In [514]: edges[_,:]   # sedges (below)
Out[514]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 13],
       [ 1,  2, 12],
       [ 4,  5, 15],
       [ 4,  5, 15],
       [ 5,  6, 18],
       [ 5,  6, 18]])
```

Now all matching rows are together.

If there always 2 matches, the pairs can be collected and reshaped into a 2 column array.

```
In [516]: sedges[:,2].reshape(-1,2)
Out[516]: 
array([[13, 12],
       [15, 15],
       [18, 18]])
```

Alternatively you could still iterate, but you don't have to check as far way.

---

`argsort` on a sorting list returns the reverse sort:

```
In [519]: np.lexsort((edges[:,1],edges[:,0]))
Out[519]: array([0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5], dtype=int32)
In [520]: np.argsort(_)
Out[520]: array([0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5], dtype=int32)
In [521]: sedges[_,:]
Out[521]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 13],
       [ 4,  5, 15],
       [ 5,  6, 18],
       [ 1,  2, 12],
       [ 4,  5, 15],
       [ 5,  6, 18]])
```

Comment: You are right, not all elements of `mat` will be filled eventually. I just didn't want to `append` elements to it in every iteration. I have thought about lexsorting, but the problem with that is I lose the information for the exact initial row counter where the row was located, as I use that information for computing the divisor and modolo. Perhaps an inverse lex-argsort is what I am looking for.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that `lexsort` gives you those indices.

Comment: You can also reverse sort with a `argsort` on the sort list.